# Page hangs when trying to load SQLSRV (PHP5 in IIS6, Windows Server 2003 R2)

Tags: php, iis-6, windows-server-2003, sql-server-native-client

I apologise if any of this sounds like a broken record but I've trawled the internet for days and have cross-referenced at least three "how to install PHP 5 with IIS 6" guides but have had no luck whatsoever. I'm trying to configure PHP 5.4 with IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003 R2, along with SQLSRV (SQL Server Native Client) for connectivity to SQL Server.

Here is what I've done so far:

1. Extracted **php-5.4.4-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.zip** to C:\PHP
2. Installed FastCGI **fcgisetup_1.5_rtw_x86.msi**
3. Downloaded Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server and extracted **php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll** and **php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll** to C:\PHP\ext
4. Modified PHP.ini with the following changes:

   error_log=C:\Windows\temp\php_errors.log
   upload_tmp_dir=C:\Windows\temp
   session.save_path=C:\Windows\temp
   cgi.force_redirect=0
   cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
   fastcgi.impersonate=1
   fastcgi.logging=0
   max_execution_time=300
   date.timezone=Europe/Dublin
   extension_dir="C:\PHP\ext\"

   extension=php_mysql.dll
   extension=php_mysqli.dll
   extension=php_mbstring.dll
   extension=php_gd2.dll
   extension=php_gettext.dll
   extension=php_curl.dll
   extension=php_exif.dll
   extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
   extension=php_openssl.dll
   extension=php_soap.dll
   extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
   extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
   extension=php_imap.dll
   extension=php_tidy.dll
   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
   extension=php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
5. Installed **Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Native Client**

If I comment out the last two extensions I can view **phpinfo()** with no problems. However as soon as they are introduced and the application pool is recycled it causes the page to hang, or phpinfo() will display but SQLSRV is not present.

Is there something I am missing?
Thanks,
valoukh

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer below and accept it. That will mark your question as solved (yes it works and it's okay to do so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem was related to me using the wrong versions of software for the server in question. For example:

1. I changed to PHP 5.3 (5.3.14) VC9 x86 Non Thread Safe
2. I uninstalled Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Native Client and installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client

I now have SQLSRV running in PHP!

Comment: I'm trying to find if PHP 5.4 works on IIS 6 but I can't find anything that says one way or another. Why did you go back to 5.3?

Comment: @paulmorriss, i think php 5.4 does work in IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003.
i think this can help you: https://web.archive.org/web/20180223160926/https://robsphp.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-install-microsofts-sql-server.html
(yes, i know it's just a link but i'm using archive.org to prevent it from 404ing)